# Javascript change a select list based on passed variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectlist

I want to pass a variable from another page and have it effect the first select in a form on my current page. For example if my url is:
currentPage.html?classType=BATR1

I want the select to display the corresponding option.

This is what I am currently trying:

```html
<script>
 function setClassType(param) {
            var val = document.URL;
            var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
            var n = url.replace(param+"=","");
            document.getElementById(n).selected = true; 
 }
 setClassType("classType");
</script>
  
<form>
  
 <select>
  <option id="test">Test</option>
  <option id="BATR1">Backflow Assembly Tester Recertification 1-Day</option>
  <option id="CCSC">Cross-Connection Specialist Update</option>
 </select>
  
</form>
```

I have also tried this:

```html
<script>
 function setClassType(param) {
            var val = document.URL;
            var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
            var n = url.replace(param+"=","");
            document.getElementById("courseType").value = n; 
 }
 setClassType("classType");
</script>
  
<form>
  
 <select id="courseType">
  <option value="test">Test</option>
  <option value="BATR1">Backflow Assembly Tester Recertification 1-Day</option>
  <option value="CCSC">Cross-Connection Specialist Update</option>
 </select>
  
</form>
```

I'm pretty much a beginner at scripting and I just can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your tags are in the wrong order, you can't nest the form inside the script, you also have an extra script closing tag. So in your HTML, have the form first, and then the script below it. Also, you call the function getParameter, which doesn't exist, you probably meant to call setClassType. That should get you started. Ps: the console tells you alot about the issues the code has.

Comment: @Shilly Thank you! fixing those has made it work!